# "Object [object Object] has no method" error online but not on localhost! Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slider, typeerror

I just put online on a test URL a website that on my local machine (WampServer 2.2) was working perfectly.

The online test urls is this one: http://clienti.stefanoginella.com/viktormitic/

Why now I receive this javacript error message? **Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'startslider'**

**startslider** is from a jQuery plugin called NerveSlider that I'm using to have some backrgound image slider.

It's been all day that I'm tryng to understand this error, but I can't figure out the solution. Expecially because on my local machine it is working properly without any problem.

Comment: Did you make sure startslider plugin is included in your server?

Comment: Have you uploaded the startslider plugin to your server? Seeing your code would help here

Comment: Yes, all the .js files are uploaded and loaded correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the [minified](http://clienti.stefanoginella.com/viktormitic/wp-content/themes/viktormitic/libs/jquery.nerveSlider.min.js) version of the neverslider javascript is all in one line and starting with a comment: `//`...

Maybe it's just that? How are you creating the minified js?

Comment: wow, thanks a lot. That was the problem... but still I don't understand why it was working on localhost and not online...
anyway I was using the original minified file I've download from the plugin website

Comment: Then maybe newline / carriage-return characters are interpreted differently on the server... Have a look at the Common Problems section here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline